# Stuck trying to get only users with same idempresa

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

In my application (developed with Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine) I'm trying to get all users based on `idempresa` of the user logged in. `idempresa` is in a `sf_guard_user_profile`table and this is the schema for that:

```
SfGuardUserProfile:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_user_profile
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(8), primary: true }
    user_id: { type: integer(8), primary: false }
    idempresa: { type: integer(4), primary: false }
  relations:
    User:
      local: user_id
      class: sfGuardUser
      type: one
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: SfGuardUserProfile
      onDelete: CASCADE
      onUpdate: CASCADE
```

I'm trying with this query:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUser')
   ->createQuery('u')
   ->leftJoin('u.Profile p')
   ->where('idempresa = ?', $id_empresa)
   ->execute();
```

But get this error:

> Unknown relation alias Profile

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relation between the `sfGuardUser` and `sfGuardUserProfile` is not called `Profile` but `SfGuardUserProfile`. So you should use in your query builder:

```
 ->leftJoin('u.SfGuardUserProfile p')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I try that but doesn't work, maybe a typo and I was tired at 2 AM, anyway thanks

Comment: It's definitely fun to write code at 2 am but you can easily get stuck with such simple mistakes. ;)